# Code to control two different classes

Tags: css

I've got the following HTML code. My CSS for `tax-details` is:

```
.products-grid .tax-details {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

I need to have a seperate css selector for `tax-details` that have the class `regular-price`. I tried the following:

```
.products-grid .regular-price .tax-details {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

but this does not work. Can somebody help me out?

```
<ul class="products-grid first odd">
   <li class="item first"> <a class="product-image" title="Navy Frotteejacke" href="urll"><img width="180" height="180" alt="Navy Frotteejacke" src="url"></a>
     <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Navy Frotteejacke" href="url">Navy Frotteejacke</a></h2>
     <div class="price-box">
       <span id="product-price-167" class="regular-price">
       <span class="price">9,00&nbsp;€</span></span>
     </div>
     <span class="tax-details">inkl. MwSt., zzgl. <a href=url">Versandkosten</a></span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you need `.products-grid .tax-details` to be `.products.grid .regular-price .tax-details`? Are you trying to change the CSS of `.tax-details`?

Comment: You do not have an element with a class of '.tax-details' within the span.regular-price, so the rule .products-grid .regular-price .tax-details will never apply to anything

Answer (score 0):

> for tax-details that have the class regular-price

=> `tax-details` hasn't a `regular-price` class associated to it in your HTML sample.

The selector: `.products-grid .regular-price .tax-details`

applies to a structure like this:

```
products-grid
    regular-price
       tax-details
```

**BUT**

Your current HTML has this structure:

```
products-grid
    regular-price
    tax-details  //not a regular-price's child
```

So don't expect it to work that way.

Refine the structure to match the CSS declaration, or change the CSS selector.

**---------From your comment just below:----------**

You could perhaps not changed the whole structure, but adding a class I hope yes:

```
<span class="tax-details regular-price">inkl. MwSt., zzgl. <a href=url">Versandkosten</a></span>
```

and the CSS becoming:

```
.products-grid .tax-details.regular-price { //note the union (without space) between tax and regular
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

For more info on this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/680-Defining-A-CSS-Selector-That-Requires-A-Multi-Class-Union.htm

Comment: It is not possible for me to change the structure of the html. How does the CSS selector have to be changed for it to work out? I'm quite new on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to change the CSS of `.tax-details` but it is not a child of `.regular-price` so that won't work.

Have you tried adding `!important;` behind your CSS like this:

```
.tax-details {
    margin-top: 0px!important;
}
```

Or if you are trying to control two classes with one code (like your title suggests) you can use this:

```
.regular-price, .tax-details {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```